# Issues while trying to create a hibernate query that navigates through many-to-many associations with additional join table entity and composite key

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have three entities: Account, AccountAttribut and Attribut. Account and Attribut are associated via AccountAttribut in a many-to-many relationship like it is described here (1). AccountAttribut is a join table entity that holds an additional attribute.

I try to build a HQL string that delivers all Accounts with the "wert"-property "John" in AccountAttribut and the name-property "FirstName" in Attribut.

I dont find the right HQL string. Can you help me out?

(1): http://giannigar.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/mapping-a-many-to-many-join-table-with-extra-column-using-jpa/ "Mapping a many-to-many join table with extra column using JPA"

I tried this query:

```
    List<Account> queried_accounts = HibernateUtils.queryList(
            session.createQuery(""
                    + "from Account as acc"
                    + " full join acc.accountAttributes as accAtt"
                    + " inner join accAtt.aa_pk.attribut as attr"
                    + " where attr.name='FirstName' and accAtt.wert='John'")
    );
```

and i get this error message:

> ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'full outer join account_attribut accountatt1_ on
>   account0_.account_id=accountatt' at line 1

**UPDATE:**
I changed the query to:

```
List<Account> queried_accounts = HibernateUtils.queryList(
        session.createQuery(""
                + "from Account as acc"
                + " inner join acc.accountAttributes as accAtt"
                + " inner join accAtt.aa_pk.attribut as attr"
                + " where attr.name='FirstName' and accAtt.wert='John'")
);
```

This seems to work.
But now i got a new Problem: queried_accounts does not seem to be a List of Accounts. If i get an object out of queried_accounts and try to apply account methods on it, i get an Exception at runtime.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   com.computacenter.qct.pojos.Account

These are relevant code extracts:

Account:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    private Long accountId;
    private List<AccountAttribut> accountAttributes = new LinkedList<AccountAttribut>();
    private Person person;
    private Zielsystem zielsystem;

    public Account() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
    public Long getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(Long accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "aa_pk.account", cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
    public List<AccountAttribut> getAccountAttributes() {
        return accountAttributes;
    }

    public void setAccountAttributes(List<AccountAttribut> accountAttribute) {
        this.accountAttributes = accountAttribute;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="zielsystem_id")
    public Zielsystem getZielsystem() {
        return zielsystem;
    }

    public void setZielsystem(Zielsystem zielsystem) {
        this.zielsystem = zielsystem;
    }
}
```

AccountAttribut:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account_attribut")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name="aa_pk.account", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="account_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name="aa_pk.attribut", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="attribut_id"))
})
public class AccountAttribut {}
private AccountAttributPk aa_pk = new AccountAttributPk();

@Column(name="wert")
private String wert;

@EmbeddedId
public AccountAttributPk getAa_pk() {
    return aa_pk;
}

public void setAa_pk(AccountAttributPk aa_pk) {
    this.aa_pk = aa_pk;
}

@Transient
public Account getAccount() {
    return getAa_pk().getAccount();
}

public void setAccount(Account account) {
    getAa_pk().setAccount(account);
}

@Transient
public Attribut getAttribut() {
    return getAa_pk().getAttribut();
}

public void setAttribut(Attribut attribut) {
    getAa_pk().setAttribut(attribut);
}

public String getWert() {
    return wert;
}

public void setWert(String wert) {
    this.wert = wert;
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
     if (this== o) return true;
     if (o ==null|| getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

     AccountAttribut that = (AccountAttribut) o;

     if (getAa_pk() !=null?!getAa_pk().equals(that.getAa_pk()) : that.getAa_pk() !=null) return false;

     return true;
}

 public int hashCode() {
     return (getAa_pk() !=null? getAa_pk().hashCode() : 0);
 }
}
```

AccountAttributPk:

```
public class AccountAttributPk implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1551814445010872872L;
    private Account account;
    private Attribut attribut;

    @ManyToOne
    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Attribut getAttribut() {
        return attribut;
    }

    public void setAttribut(Attribut attribut) {
        this.attribut = attribut;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        AccountAttributPk that = (AccountAttributPk) o;

        if (account != null ? !account.equals(that.account) : that.account != null)
            return false;
        if (attribut != null ? !attribut.equals(that.attribut)
                : that.attribut != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = (account != null ? account.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (attribut != null ? attribut.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Attribut

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Attribut")
public class Attribut {

    private Long attributId;
    private String name;
    private List<PersonAttribut> personenAttribute = new LinkedList<PersonAttribut>();
    private List<AccountAttribut> accountAttribute = new LinkedList<AccountAttribut>();
    private List<BerechtigungsobjektAttribut> berechtigungsobjektAttribute = new LinkedList<BerechtigungsobjektAttribut>(); 

    public Attribut() {}

    public Attribut(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
    @Column(name="attribut_id", nullable=false)
    public Long getAttributId() {
        return attributId;
    }

    public void setAttributId(Long attributId) {
        this.attributId = attributId;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pa_pk.attribut", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    public List<PersonAttribut> getPersonenAttribute() {
        return personenAttribute;
    }

    public void setPersonenAttribute(List<PersonAttribut> personenAttribute) {
        this.personenAttribute = personenAttribute;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "aa_pk.attribut", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    public List<AccountAttribut> getAccountAttribute() {
        return accountAttribute;
    }

    public void setAccountAttribute(List<AccountAttribut> accountAttribute) {
        this.accountAttribute = accountAttribute;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ba_pk.attribut", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    public List<BerechtigungsobjektAttribut> getBerechtigungsobjektAttribute() {
        return berechtigungsobjektAttribute;
    }

    public void setBerechtigungsobjektAttribute(
            List<BerechtigungsobjektAttribut> berechtigungsobjektAttribute) {
        this.berechtigungsobjektAttribute = berechtigungsobjektAttribute;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        if (this == other)
            return true;
        if (this.getClass() != other.getClass())
            return false;

        final Attribut otherAccount = (Attribut) other;
        return EqualsUtils.nullSafeEquals(this.getName(), otherAccount.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int PRIME = 42;
        return this.name.hashCode() * PRIME;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's this "full join". Use `inner join`, or simply `join`. Side note: everything would be so much easier if you treated the AccountAttribut entity like all the other entities, and thus used a single-column, autogenerated ID.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Thx for your reply. I replaced the full join with inner join. Now it works. What would i have won, if i introduce an autogenerated ID in AccountAttribut? The solution under (1) does not use an additional ID for the join entity.

Comment: You win the fact that your code is simpler, than it's more consistent, and that you don't need two objects of type Account and Attribut to refer to an AccountAttribut, but simply a Long. Tables referencing the AccountAttribut table will also need a single column instead of 2.

Comment: Ok, the code gets simpler. I got that. And i think ill come back to your suggestion and implement that. But for now, id like to solve the first problem. There is a new problem as written in the update section. The hql string does not deliver Account objects, but something different. I cannot apply account methods on elements of the resultlist. I get an exception (see Update section)

Comment: The query should be `select distinct acc from Account as acc ...`